# Is there a way to set a button onClick function to a function on a prefab that is not in a Scene in Unity?

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, onclick

I have a prefab that instantiate on running the program. The prefab is not already in the scene. On this prefab there is a script with a function that should be called when a button is clicked.The button is in the scene. In the button's inspector I drag and dropped the prefab and chose the function to execute. But on running, I get an exception. Is there a way for the button to reference a function on a prefab that is not in the scene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from making handler static, you can just find the instance of the button:

```
public class MyScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        Button myButton = GetReferenceToButton();
        myButton.onClick.AddListener ((UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction) this.OnClick);
    }

    public void OnClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked!");
    }

    private Button GetReferenceToButton()
    {
        Button btn = null;
        //Find it here
        return btn;
    }
}
```

Also you need to cast the delegate to `UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction` before adding is as listener.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I''m trying to implement your solution but I have a problem. Here's a link to it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633143/get-a-reference-to-a-button-from-script-in-unity

Answer (score 2):

If you have a user interface with multiple buttons in a prefab instantiated programmatically, you can use `GetComponentsInChildren` to access all the buttons:

```
public void onUIcreated()
{
    // Add event listeners to all buttons in the canvas
    Button[] buttons = canvasPrefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
    {
        string identifier = buttons[i].name;
        buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(delegate { OnButtonTapped(identifier); });
    }
}

public void OnButtonTapped(string identifier)
{
    Debug.Log("Pressed button:" + identifier);
}
```