# Get a reference to a button from script in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to a prefab that is not in a scene. The button has its tag.

I tried drag and dropping the button in the inspector, but the engine won't let me. I tried finding it by tag, but I get an exception "Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.GameObject to UnityEngine.UI.Button " and when I cast I get an exception that I cannot convert these types via built-in conversion. 
Some help? 
How do I get a reference to a button?
Here is the code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TankShooting : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform ShootingCameraTransform;
    private PlayerTankMovement playerTankMovement;
    public Button shootButton;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        shootButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ShootButton") as Button;
        shootButton.onClick.AddListener ((UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction)this.OnShootButtonClick);

        playerTankMovement = GetComponent<PlayerTankMovement> ();
        Transform t = transform;
        foreach (Transform tr in t)
        {
            if (tr.tag == "ShootingCamera") 
            {
                ShootingCameraTransform = tr.transform;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnShootButtonClick()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Success");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, since you used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39617471/3785314) solution, why not accept it as answer?

Comment: I''m not sure that it works. I have a problem referencing a button. If it works I will accept it. It's the checkmark thing on the left right? Can you help with the referencing the button?

Comment: Yes, the checkmark thing not the upvote or downvote image. So, if you ask a question and the answer you got does not work, do not create a new one with the non working answer. Instead, leave a comment under the answer. I am sure those people are willing to help you more answer your question. If you ignore them and then use their code in a new question, it means that the code they made solved your problem and you are now having a new different problem.

Comment: Thanks on the advice. I will used it in the future

Comment: Ok, so what's your problem?

Comment: I cannot drag and drop the button in the inspector and when I find it by tag I cannot cast it from GameObject to Button

Comment: Ok. I am writing an answer. For your old question , [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) is how to accept answer.

Comment: Do you have the code where you instantiate the prefab?

Comment: I am using this function

Comment: 'public GameObject grass;' ' Instantiate (grass, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);' . You just need to drag and drop the prefab on this script in the inspector

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your code, there is another problem:

```
shootButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ShootButton") as Button;
```

You cannot cast Component(`Button`) to GameObject like that. You have to use `GetComponent` to get the `Button` component from the GameObject.

> I cannot drag and drop the button in the inspector and when I find it
>   by tag I cannot cast it from GameObject to Button

That's because the the GameObject you are dragging to the shootButton slot is not a Button or does not have the Button component attached to it. It must have the Button component for you to be able to drag it to the `Button`(shootButton ) slot.

You have to create a Button then drag that Button to the `shootButton`  slot.

You can do that by first **removing**

```
shootButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ShootButton") as Button;
shootButton.onClick.AddListener ((UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction)this.OnShootButtonClick);
```

then drag the `Button` to the `shootButton`  slot:

[image]

**OR**

get the reference from script:

If you want to do this from script, replace

```
shootButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ShootButton") as Button;
shootButton.onClick.AddListener ((UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction)this.OnShootButtonClick);
```

with

```
shootButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ShootButton").GetComponent<Button>();
shootButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OnShootButtonClick());
```

Comment: I have the button component attached, but it's still not working

Comment: You are doing something wrong. If you can't still drag it in the slot, post a screenshot of where you are dragging it. Post another screenshot of the GameObject you are dragging into the slot and show us what Components are attached to it. Also, don't accept answer unless your problem is fixed.

Comment: Problem is fixed I used  the part _shootButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ShootButton").GetComponent<Button>();
shootButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OnShootButtonClick());_

Comment: you cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Button' via a reference conversion.